# How do I exclude null values in a WHERE clause which refers to two fields added together?

Tags: sql

I want to exclude `null` values but I'm not sure how to refer to my field which in turn refers to two other fields added together. I've tried the following but it returns nothing. The rest of the code seems to work, as when I exclude the `WHERE` clause it comes back with some results. Referring to it as `Total_Comms` brings back an error saying the name is not valid.

I'm using SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT
t.[TENANCY-REF] AS tenancyref, c.countcomms + j. countjobs  AS Total_Comms
FROM
[RE-TENANCY] t
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CommCount c
ON t.[TENANCY-REF] = c.tenancyref
LEFT OUTER JOIN #JobCount j
ON t.[TENANCY-REF] = j.tenancyref

WHERE (c.countcomms + j.countjobs) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You should edit the question and say which database you're using as some don't support null.

Comment: If you exclude the where clause, do you have values in `Total_Comms` that _aren't_ `null`?

Comment: did you try "where c.countcomms is not null and j.countjobs is not null" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need, use and/or. Use and if both values cannot be null. Use or if at least one of the two values cant be null.

```
 SELECT
    t.[TENANCY-REF] AS tenancyref, c.countcomms + j. countjobs  AS Total_Comms
    FROM
    [RE-TENANCY] t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #CommCount c
    ON t.[TENANCY-REF] = c.tenancyref
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #JobCount j
    ON t.[TENANCY-REF] = j.tenancyref

    WHERE 

    (c.countcomms IS NOT NULL and/or j.countjobs is not null)
```

Comment: Thank you - I haven't been able to test this out yet due to other problems with my query but I'm pretty sure I need to use OR!